# Can't get rid of ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I took a look at the other questions regarding this error in stackoverflow but wasn't able to get an answer. I have the following code:

```
def getKnownFace():

    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("filename.jpg")
    unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, unknown_face_encoding)
    name = ''
    if True in matches:
        first_match_index = matches.index(True)
        name = known_face_names[first_match_index]
        print(name)

        return name
```

That's the error I get:

```
  File "D:/Universitet/CheckKnownFace.py", line 100, in <module>
    getKnownFace()
  File "D:/Universitet/CheckKnownFace.py", line 91, in getKnownFace
    if True in matches:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

matches

```
<class 'list'>
[array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True])]
```

I tried a couple of variants with `.any()` and `.all()` but I always get an error saying that a bool type or a list type doesn't have an all() or any() method.

What should I do for it to work properly?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace so we can know which line is even generating the error.

Comment: `any` and `all` are Python built-in functions not methods.

Comment: @RandomDavis sorry, I forgot to. Updated it now.

Comment: What does `matches` contain? As in, what are the types of its elements?

Comment: @RandomDavis added it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `matches` is a list with a single element of a `numpy` array. Simply change

`if True in matches`

to

`if True in matches[0]`

Of course, it depends on whether or not matches will contain more than on numpy array. If so, you might have to do a for loop or provide other logic, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks mate. Matches can contain more than one numpy array so I went with the for loop implementation.